# Use beamer overlays in "normal" latex document

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have some pretty complicated tikz figures with a lot of overlays in external .tex files included in my beamer presentation.

To write my paper, it would be very convenient for me to just "pick" one of the slides to be displayed in my normal article class document, withouth touching the .tex file. Like you can do with frames: `\begin{frame}<3> ...`.

Is that in any way possible? I couldn't find anything on that.

Example:

*figure.tex*

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node<1> {A};
  \node<2> {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And then something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
...
\onlyslide{1}{\include{figure.tex}} % renderns only 'A' node 
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could already define in your tikz files which nodes should be (in-)visible in the article version. This allows you to reuse the same files for your article without having to touch them again.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node<1|article:0> {A};
  \node<2> {B};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: didn't knew about the `\usepackage{beamerarticle}`, wans't easy to find :D But this works great for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @semklauke You're welcome!